# Escape string build of objects C#

Tags: c#, escaping

I read some values from config files and add them to string then escape it.

Here is example:

```
_confi = new Config();
Configuration.GetSection("Config").Bind(_confi);

string mySuperComplicatedString = $"Lorem ipsum {_confi.value} bla bla bla {_config.value2}";
```

Issue is if I try to escape my super complicated string I will have to put it like that:

```
$\"Lorem ipsum {_confi.value} bla bla bla {_config.value2}\"
```

Than my {_confi.value} and {_config.value2} will be part of my string but it won't be read from my config file. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need to "escape" the string?

Comment: I need to deserialize it into JSON and test many different variation of it. So having dozens of JSON files in my solution is not best way :/

Comment: Ok, to my knowledge that still would not be valid Json. Valid json would look something like `{"config": "Lorem ipsum _confi.value bla bla bla _config.value2"}`

Comment: Ok, let me be more precise: heres my example:
`$"{ \"Lorem\":\"{_config.value}\",\"Ipsum\":\"{_config.value2}\"}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always use the old concatenation syntax:

```
string myString = "{\"Lorem\":" + _config1 + "\",\"Ipsum\":" + _config2 + "\"}";
```